# Firebug - how to reduce indentation of nodes?

Tags: css, firebug

Is there any way to access the stylesheets that make up firebug to edit things like the indent distance for nested DOM nodes? Looking for a location of some .css files or something that I can override.

I frequently find myself working with deeply-nested nodes that are pressed up against the right side of firebug, while the whole left side is unusable whitespace.

Comment: Have you checked the Firebug WIKI? http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I have looked around a bit, and found that searching in the wiki for "css", "firebug chrome" or any other obvious thing to search for returns results that are mainly about using firebug, not developing/hacking the source.

Comment: you could open firebug in its own window. that will give you more room to play with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stylish Firefox extension, you can use this code to remove the indentation in the dom panel.
I have to look further to see how to decrease the indentation on child nodes (it's a good userstyle project, btw) :

```
.memberLabelCell{
padding-left:0 !important;
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a little userstyle which reduces the indentation of nodes in html and dom panels : http://userstyles.org/styles/42885
(you need [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) to use it)

Comment: brilliant. Using stylish to override the plugin output seems like the optimal way to reduce indentation. Many thanks.